# Mysql table instant update using Jquery/Ajax without submission

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

In my PHP project I want to make a form where the input data can be automatically updated in a MySQL table and display the values. I think its related with jQuery/ajax or I am confused is it a JSON project?

So how do I do this?

Comment: So what do u want to know ???

Comment: You will most likely use AJAX (whether you do it with pure JavaScript, jQuery, or another library) to do this, but your question is a bit too broad to be answered here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done with keypress/keyup/keydown event with jquery ajax. Just simply send an ajax request to your PHP script which will save or update data to your database on every keypress/keyup/keydown with the value you just typed.

```
$('#yourTextBoxId').keypress(function(e){ 
   var myValue = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
      url:'yourphpfile.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data:{myValue:myValue}
   });
});
```